# Using an Audio Library in a Flutter project?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, audiokit, juce

I'm considering building my app with Flutter because of the attractive cross-compilation features, native feel, and speed of development.

I need to use an advanced audio processing library to be able to make my app, so the options I was considering are either to use JUCE through CocoaPods (a C++ audio library) or AudioKit (a Swift audio library) with Flutter.

I think JUCE is definitely possible to use with Flutter as I've seen two github projects which seemed to implement it (https://github.com/audiooffler/JucyFluttering and https://github.com/tomduncalf/juce-flutter-integration). I haven't been able to get it running on my own setup though, the build succeeds but when I use the first link (JucyFluttering) but I get an error as follows: https://justpaste.it/9c8xe. I've tried to look into it for a while and couldn't figure out what is going wrong. If anyone has an idea or approach to move from here

The other option I was considering is building an iOS only app for my prototype using Flutter and AudioKit (Swift-based), and then reusing the Flutter UI code with JUCE when I want to move to cross-platform. However, I'm totally clueless on how to go about bringing AudioKit into my Flutter project. The library is not on pub.dev so including it in my pubspec.yaml file, I get the following: "Because audiokit_flutter depends on audiokit any which doesn't exist (could not find package audiokit at https://pub.dartlang.org), version solving failed." when I try to run "flutter pub get".

I'm not even sure if the AudioKit approach is viable, but if anyone has any relevant knowledge, please share it with me! I've been trying to figure this out for weeks and it has been very frustrating! I would very very much appreciate the help.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Were you able to make any progress on this? What approach did you follow?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this question while googling and I have come across the original Jucy-Fluttering repo but also found out it wasn't working so I made a working version of it. I can't remember exactly what I did to fix it but here is a link to the repo version - https://github.com/txbrown/JucyFluttering-Working